# Apache File upload, FileItemIterator is empty

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons

I want a simple image capture/upload on mobile devices. For the actual file upload, i use Apache Commons. Now I encountered the same problem as described here: [Apache commons fileupload FileItemIterator hasNext() returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184917/apache-commons-fileupload-fileitemiterator-hasnext-returns-false), but I can't find out where the request might have been consumed before my post method.

I tested it on my development machine, when i put in any file (image or not), the iterator is simpy empty.

Here is everything I have, I marked the actual file upload code so you don't have to sift through everything.

Thanks for the help!

```
@WebServlet("/scanner")
public class MyServiceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int maxFileSize = 50 * 1024;
    private static final int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
    private static final String saveFolder = "/";

    private final String repoFolder;
    private final DiskFileItemFactory factory;

    public MyServiceServlet() {
        final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if (os.contains("Windows"))
            repoFolder = "C:\\temp";
        else
            repoFolder = "/tmp";

        factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

        // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
        factory.setRepository(new File(this.repoFolder));
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("get");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("MyService/start.html").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Post");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>MyService</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            out.println("<p>Nothing uploaded</p>");

        } else {

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            // maximum file size to be uploaded.
            upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);


                    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FILE UPLOAD HERE
                    try {
            FileItemIterator it = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    String contentType = item.getContentType();
                    boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
                    long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();
                    file = new File(saveFolder + fileName);
                    item.write(file);
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            this.printUserForm(out);
        }

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

start.html file, I may have missed something here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>MyService</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="input" action="/MySercice/scanner">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml, if it helps. But there is nothing here, really

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>MyService</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>start.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
```

Comment: I can't. Apparently the new commons API kicked the parseRequest(request) for parseRequest(RequestContext). From what I've read, this shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Seam:
Following @CR7 suggestion, I could make it work by adding the below config to the components.xml

```
<web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="true"  
                      max-request-size="1024000" url-pattern="*"/>
```

Ps: I don't know why, but for me, any other value I put in url-pattern makes the list returns empty.